# Deleting Files and Directories not working

Tags: java, android, directory, delete-file

I am trying to delete all the files inside a directory then the directory afterwards using the below code but it doesn't seem to work. (Files are not deleted after the method ran).

```
public void DeleteDirectory() {
        ArrayList<File> Directories = new ArrayList<File>();
        Directories.add(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString().concat("/AssetControl/Images")));
        Directories.add(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString().concat("/AssetControl/Thumbnails")));

        ListIterator<File> itr = Directories.listIterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            File dir = itr.next();
                if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                String[] files = dir.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    (new File(files[i])).delete();
                    // This is also not working:
                    // File current = new File(files[i]);
                    // current.delete();
                }
                dir.delete();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please use the proper `File` constructor, rather than string concatenation. Beyond that, please explain what "it doesnt seem to work" means.

Comment: I think its quite obvious what i am trying to do "delete all the files inside the directory and then the directory" (AS STATED) but "it" doesnt seem to work. I did use the proper file constructor and same result NO DELETION.

Comment: What did you learn when you stepped through your code in a debugger, or added `Log.d()` calls to see what portions of your code were and were not executed? "I did use the proper file constructor" -- not in the code that is in your question. Your second and third lines use `concat()` to build a file path, which is unreliable.

Comment: I went through the debugger and it executed correctly. any other suggestion? what other option do you suggest i use instead of concat() to build a file path?

Comment: "I went through the debugger and it executed correctly" -- OK, how are you determining whether or not the files are deleted? DDMS' File Explorer? **`adb shell`**? Something else? "what other option do you suggest i use instead of concat() to build a file path?" -- `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/AssetControl/Images")`.

Comment: I went through DDMS and they are still showing there.

Comment: OK, that is strange. Does your app hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? You should be crashing if you do not, but I am running out of suggestions.

Comment: Yes it does have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Thanks for your response. I got it working when i switched from String array to File array.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
replaced String[] files with File[] files.

```
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            File dir = itr.next();
                if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    DeleteFile(files[i]);
                }
                dir.delete();
            }
        }
```